# Replace match string from string statement c#

Tags: c#, string

```
 string l_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"
 string findString = "C:\\Windows";

 if (l_path.Contains(findString )) // C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe
 {
     string l_EnvironmentVariable = l_path.Replace(findString , "WinDir");
 }
```

I want to get exact match from string statement. But when I check contains method its checking for any character match.. result (`l_EnvironmentVariable`) should be like **"WINDIR\System32\calc.exe"**

Comment: `C:\\Winodws` -> `C:\\Windows`?

Comment: "i want to get exact match from string statement" what does this have to do with `Contains`? What are you trying to achieve and why is it not working? "its checking for any character match".. yes that is the `Contains` function literal purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Let's **Split** each path into its parts (`SplitPath`):

```
private static string[] SplitPath(string value) {
  Queue<string> parts = new Queue<string>();

  for (DirectoryInfo diValue = new DirectoryInfo(value);
       diValue != null;
       diValue = diValue.Parent)
    parts.Enqueue(diValue.Name);

  return parts.Reverse().ToArray();
}
```

And then we can operate with these parts (compare and modify):

```
string l_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
string findString = "C:\\Windows";

var l_path_parts = SplitPath(l_path);
var findString_parts = SplitPath(findString);

// If l_path starts from findString
var startsFrom = l_path_parts
  .Zip(findString_parts, (a, b) => string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .All(item => item);

string l_EnvironmentVariable = startsFrom 
  ? Path.Combine(
      new string[] { Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WinDir") }.Concat(l_path_parts
        .Skip(findString_parts.Length))
        .ToArray())
  : l_path; 

Console.Write(l_EnvironmentVariable);
```

**Outcome:** (depends on `WinDir` environment variable; if it's `D:\Windows`)

```
D:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
```

Please, note that we compare paths by their *parts*, and that's why

```
string l_path = "C:\\WindowsToTest\\System32\\calc.exe";
```

*fails* to match `C:\\Windows` (since `WindowsToTest != Windows`) and we'll get

```
l_EnvironmentVariable == C:\WindowsToTest\System32\calc.exe
```

Comment: I have Environment variable list WinDir is not be constant

Comment: @John: then let's read `WinDir` environment variable: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WinDir")` instead of `"WinDir"`. See my edit; Another option is  `"%WinDir%"` and let system put environment variable